# android webview loadurl() with apostrophe char into string

Tags: android, url, android-webview, special-characters

i try to load this url into my webview : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbaye_d'Engelberg but it dont work cause it contains ' character how can i fix it please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please put the url like below

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbaye_d%27Engelberg

url encoding for ' is %27

Comment: it worked with  url = url.replaceAll("\'","%27"); thanks rep++

Answer (score 1):

Just put a backslash: Eg. Load the url `https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbaye_d\'Engelberg`

Note the backslash before the `'` character.

Comment: i already tried it with myurl.replaceall but i didn't managed to get it working, what is the pattern to doit? all other special char seems to work

Comment: @Noj I'm a little rusty in java, but it would be something like this: `myUrl.replaceAll("\'", "\\\'")` Though if you are loading a String variable it should work. When you say it doesn't work, does it crash?

Comment: @Noj If the app crashes then please post the logcat info

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue, in android-webview ( react-native ) so to fix this I have used ...

```
document.replace(/\'/g, "\\\'")
```